# Dynamics 365 - Create workflow on new Eventbrite contact

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, eventbrite, clickdimension

New to Dynamics 365, ClickDimensions and Eventbrite integration.

When a user registers on Eventbrite it creates a new contact within our CRM as it's meant to do.  What I cannot figure out is how to create a workflow that sends an email back to the user from the CRM but only if it has come from Eventbrite.

I know how to create a workflow when a contact is created, but not with the extra check.

Comment: Do you want to send an email when the contact is initially created or every time that the person registers to an event?

Comment: Just when the contact is first created (so once only)